Duplicating tables from database1 to database2 LIKE on same server fails, error 1064
I've been reading the MariaDB manual and tutorials and apparently this should work:
EXPLAIN CREATE TABLE `prefix_database2`.`table1` LIKE `prefix_database1`.`table1`;`

The LIKE operator is supposed to duplicate the table columns and keys. I'm at a loss at why I'm getting the syntax error.
How do I duplicate a table in a second database from the first while maintaining the exact same columns, keys, etc?

you can not use explain for that command. run it with out it and everything works fine

@nbk Thank you, if you post an answer I'll accept it.

EXPLAIN doesn't support CREATE TABLE
the supported commands are:

EXPLAIN tbl_name [col_name | wild]

Or

EXPLAIN [EXTENDED | PARTITIONS | FORMAT=JSON]
{SELECT select_options | UPDATE update_options | DELETE delete_options}

see manual
Use the CREATE command without EXPLAIN and it works as expected

Thank you nbk..
